# Composer pull from forked GitHub with Autoload

Tags: github, composer-php, ffmpeg-php

So I'm trying to use composer to install this php-ffmpeg extension here:

https://github.com/sharapov-outsource/php-ffmpeg-extensions

But it requires php-ffmpeg 0.6.1 and the newest version of php-ffmpeg is 0.9.3
So how can I use composer to install this and allow version 0.9.3 of the php-ffmpeg? Do I need to fork it? If so, how do I set up my composer.json file to pull and set the right classes?

Answer (score 2):

**For composer installation,**

1) add:

```
"require": {
     "sharapov/php-ffmpeg-extensions": "0.9.3"
},
```

to your composer.json file and update your dependencies.

```
$ composer update
```

---

2) Or you can run from shell:

```
$ composer require sharapov/php-ffmpeg-extensions:0.9.3
```

---

**Version to use can be defined in the following ways:**

- `1.2` You can specific the version of package (ex., `0.9.3` or `0.6.1`)
- The `^` (caret) operator means any non-breaking version / until major (e.g., `^1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3<2.0.0`)
- The `~` (tilde) operator means approximate / increment right most digit (e.g., `~1.2` is equivalent to `>=1.2<2.0.0` or `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0`)
- The `*` (star) operator means all versions on this level (e.g., `1.0.*` is the equivalent of `>=1.0<1.1`)
- The `1.0-2.0` is the the equivalent of `>=1.0.0<2.1`

For more look a doc of composer https://getcomposer.org/doc/

Comment: But I don't need version 0.9.3 of the ffmpeg extensions. The package requires regular php-ffmpeg 0.6.1 but the newest version of php-ffmpeg is 0.9.3. I can't edit the composer.json file in the ffmpeg-extensions to allow for php-ffmpeg 0.9.3

Comment: then add php-ffmpeg to your composer:
composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg:0.9.3